# Angular, button requires 2 clicks to change text

Tags: angular, indexing, angular-directive

I'm a beginner to angular and this a quiz application in which I'm stuck in a problem where clicking button requires 2 clicks. At first click, it works fine but when I click on any button, then next and back buttons would require double clicking to go back or next to the next question.

**html:**

```
<div class="qblock" *ngIf="search">
      <div class="qheader">
        <h2>{{ search.questionNumber }}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="qdescription">
        <p>
          {{ search.questionText }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="qactions text-right">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="previous(search.index)">
        Back
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="next(search.index)">
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
public QuizData: any = {};
public number = 0;
  public search: any;
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.QuizData = [
      {
        index: 0,
        questionNumber: 'Question 1',
        questionText:
          'Test question 1',
        options: [
          {
            optionLabel: 'A',
            optionText: 'Option A',
            optionActive: false,
          },
          {
            optionLabel: 'B',
            optionText: 'Option B',
            optionActive: false,
          },
          {
            optionLabel: 'C',
            optionText: 'Option C',
            optionActive: false,
          },
          {
            optionLabel: 'D',
            optionText: 'Option D',
            optionActive: false,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        index: 2,
        questionNumber: 'Question 2',
        questionText:
          'Test question 2',
        options: [
          {
            optionLabel: 'A',
            optionText: 'Option A',
            optionActive: false,
          },
          {
            optionLabel: 'B',
            optionText: 'Option B',
            optionActive: false,
          },
          {
            optionLabel: 'C',
            optionText: 'Option C',
            optionActive: false,
          },
          {
            optionLabel: 'D',
            optionText: 'Option D',
            optionActive: false,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    this.number = 0;
    let currentQuestion = this.QuizData[this.number];
    this.number = this.number + 1;
    this.search = currentQuestion;
  }

next(index) {
    let count = Object.keys(this.QuizData).length;
    index = index + 1;
     if (this.number == count) {
       alert('you reached last index');
       this.number = this.number - 1;
       return;
     }
    let nextQuestion = this.QuizData[this.number];
    if (this.number < count) {
      this.number = this.number + 1;
    }
    this.search = nextQuestion;
  }
  previous(index) {
    index = index - 1;
    this.number = this.number - 1;
    if (this.number < 0) {
      this.number = 0;
      return;
    }
    let previousQuestion = this.QuizData[this.number];
    this.search = previousQuestion;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Ammaar, welcome to SO! After the app loads, does clicking on next immediately causes nothing or does the first click works? Also, if first click works, does clicking on next again doesn't work?

Comment: Hey @frunkad first click works, after that it requires double clicks to move to next or previous question

Comment: Apparently that could be because there are only two entries. Try adding a couple more question and let us know the behaviour. Would be helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jt5zcz)

remove `this.number = this.number + 1;` from constructor . Your first index is 0;

then update your events like below

```
 next(index) {
    let count = Object.keys(this.QuizData).length;
    this.number++;
     if (this.number == count) {
       alert('you reached last index'); 
       this.number --;
       return;
     }
    let nextQuestion = this.QuizData[this.number];
    this.search = nextQuestion;
  }
  previous(index) {
    this.number --;
    if (this.number < 0) {
      this.number = 0;
      return;
    }
    let previousQuestion = this.QuizData[this.number];
    this.search = previousQuestion;
  }
```